# What's the equivalent of getElementsByTagName() in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo

What's the equivalent of getElementsByTagName() in DOJO?

eg:

```
<input id="inserviceInputId" type="text" value="09/05/2003" name="inserviceInput" style="width:7em">
```

So for this, I am trying to get the element via name="inserviceInput".

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me to be the `.query` method, which ostensibly wraps `document.querySelector` or possibly Sizzle.  You can use any attribute in the query including `name`.  If you wanted to use `getElementsByTagName` you could always use that too since it's still available.

```
require(["dojo/query"], function(query){
  console.log(query("[name=inserviceInput]"));
});
```

[Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/query.html)

Answer (score 1):

Dojo is a framework built on top of JavaScript, not a language. `getElementsByTagName` is a native JavaScript function.

So the Dojo equivalent of `getElementsByTagName` is ... `getElementsByTagName`.